# How to get the column sum total values of last 2 column's in this dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The below code is used to add new row to the table, also multiply two fields and show the result in the final field, in this dynamically generated row and at last part of code, removes the added row if it is not needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('.add-box').click(function() {
  var box_html = $('<tr class="multLote"><td align="center"><input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;" /></td> ' +
    '<td><textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100" > </textarea></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20" /></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10" /></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" disabled name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="0"></td>' +
    '<th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a></th></tr>');

  $('#tabela-lotes tbody').append(box_html);
  return false;
});

$('#tabela-lotes').on("keyup", ".multLote input", function() {
  var mult = 0;
  // for each row:
  console.log($(this).closest('table').find("tr.multLote").length);
  $(this).closest('tr.multLote').each(function() {
    // get the values from this row:
    var $val20 = $('.val20', this).val();
    var $val10 = $('.val10', this).val();
    console.log($val100);
    var $total = ($val20 * $val10);
    console.log($total);
    // set total for the row
    $('.lote_result', this).val($total);
    mult += $total;
  });
});

$('#tabela-lotes').on('click', '.remove-box', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr.multLote').remove();
});

});


</script>
```

This is the html code.

```
 <form action="tabledb.php" method="POST">
<body>
  <input type="button" class="add-box" value="Add">
<table id="tabela-lotes">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
SL. NO
</th>
<th>
PRODUCT NAME
</th>
<th>
RATE PER CB
</th>
<th>
CBs
</th>
<th>
AMOUNT
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody><tr class="multLote">
    <td align="center">
      <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="lote100[]" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100" value="0"> </textarea>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="lote20[]" class="val20" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="lote10[]" class="val10" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<table>
<tr><th>
Total CBS :</th>
<td> <input type="text" name="total_cbs" id="total_cbs" placeholder="Total CBS" style="height:25px;font-weight:bold;" onfocus="cal1()" readonly ></td></tr>
<tr><th>Total AMOUNT : </th>
<td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total Rs." style="height:25px;font-weight:bold;" onfocus="cal2('.$i.')" readonly></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to the get the total coloumn sum of **lote10[ ]** and **lote_result[ ]** fields to be displayed in the **total_cbs** and **total** fields respectively.Please help, Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnlGC.jpg)
*I have updated my question with the image of the output, which states exactly what i need, Thank You.*

Comment: I tried to use the loop and get the sum, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the end result looks like this:

```js
var result = 0;
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i > elements.length - 3; i--) {
  var inputs = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
  result += parseInt(inputs[inputs.length - 1].value);
}
console.log('total', result);
alert('total ' + result);
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="multLote">
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="7">
      </td>
      <th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="multLote">
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="7">
      </td>
      <th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="multLote">
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="7">
      </td>
      <th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="multLote">
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="7">
      </td>
      <th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="multLote">
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="lote[]" value="0" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="lote100[]" value="0" style="height:25px;font-size:10pt;width:60;font-weight:bold;" class="val100"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote20[]" value="0" class="val20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lote10[]" value="0" class="val10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="lote_result[]" class="lote_result" value="7">
      </td>
      <th><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remover</a>
      </th>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uncg7Lar/)

Comment: Yes this is the output i want. I have updated my question with the output image, which shows exact output needed. It will be very helpful if anyone can guide me.